# $getJson .. action method not called

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I've read the docs and googled of this, but not seeing what the problem is.
I'm trying to get some data from a local json file.  I've validated the response data at JSONLint

**Code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 console.log("hello world 1 ");
  //BEGIN
  $.getJSON("data.json", function(myjson) {
    console.log(myjson.AC + "hello world 2");
    console.log("hello world 3 ");
  });
});
```

**data.json**

```
{
    "AC":"ONE ",
    "AD":"LETTER",
    "AE":"PEN",
    "AG":"BOOK"
}
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction that'd be great. Sorry for the huge post, it needed a bit of explaining to make it coherent. Hopefully it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Pop open your console and head to the Network tab - you'll be able to watch your request as it's made. What is the error that occurs?

Answer (score 1):

You have a fundamental misunderstanding about how the browser works. You cannot access local files through jQuery (or any way on the browser).

`$.getJSON` must be passed a URL that returns the JSON file. If you specify a valid URL, your code should work.

Comment: That's not completely true. You can enable local file access via Ajax in Chrome (and browsers probably as well). After all, browsers can also open local files, so it's not too far fetched to also access local files via Ajax. `data.json` is just a relative URI. *edit:* Unless you mean that pages loaded from a different URL cannot access local files. That's of course completely true and can't be changed.